# Angular/js select option

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Pessoal tenho um angular e uma html:

Tenho um `id` que está numa variável (`input hidden`).

Como posso fazer para comparar o `id` deste `select/option` com o `id` que está no conteúdo desta variável? A lista vem corretamente mas não estou conseguindo fazer esta comparação e setar default o `id` que vem desta variável.

html:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
<script>console.log(obj)
document.getElementById('myField').value = obj;
</script>
<input type="text" id="myField" name="myField" value="" />
<select class="form-control" name="cadastro" ng-options="cadastro.id for cadastro in (cadastro| orderBy:'id' | filter:{active:true}) track by 'id'" ng-model="cadastro" ng-selected="id=myField">
</select>
</div>
```

js:

```
function loadCadastro() {

var req = gatewayClient.delivery('lista').request('listCadstro');
requestMonitor.add('cadastro', req);
gatewayClient.execute(req).then(function(result) {
$rootScope.cadastro = result.data.value;

})
}
```

Desde já agradeço

Answer (score -1):

Pelo que entendi você quer iniciar o `<select>` com um valor pré-definido.

Para isso você pode usar o `ng-init` na tag, só que você não pode usar somente o valor do `id`, ou setar o objeto todo, você precisa encontrar o index na lista que você usou no `ng-options` assim o escopo do angular fará a "referência" correta. Eu criei um exemplo executável para ficar mais fácil, mas usei alguns nomes diferentes dos seus, mas acho que dá pra ter uma ideia. Qualquer dúvida é só chamar.

--

O primeiro problema no segundo exemplo que você postou está no `ng-model` você não pode usar o mesmo nome da variável que recebeu a lista.

O segundo problema está no `ng-options` a parte que diz você precisa passar o nome da lista e nome da variável que vai representar um item da lista `item in lista`, no seu caso, `cadastro in cadastros`.

E terceiro problema, o `ng-model` do `<select>` de um a lista de objetos precisa ser um objeto, para que angular possa trackear e selecionar o item que você precisa.

Eu editei o exemplo abaixo de acordo com o seu segundo exemplo.

```js
angular
  .module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope){
  //Carrega o valor do input hidden
  var obj = document.getElementById('myField').value;

  //Altere esse array pela sua request
  $scope.cadastros = [
    {
      cadastroNumber: "Maçã",
      id: 10,
      active: true
    },
    {
      cadastroNumber: "Banana",
      id: 12,
      active: false
    },
    {
      cadastroNumber: "Abacaxi",
      id: 20,
      active: true
    },
    {
      cadastroNumber: "Melancia",
      id: 13,
      active: true
    }
  ];
    
  //Encontra o index do objeto que deve ser selecionado
  $scope.cadastros.map(function(value, index){
    if(value.id == obj){
      $scope.indexDefault = index;
      return;
    }
  })
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    <input type="hidden" id="myField" name="myField" value="10" />
    <select name="cadastro" 
       ng-options="
        cadastro.cadastroNumber 
        for cadastro 
        in (cadastros|orderBy:'id' | filter:{active:true})
        track by cadastro.id
       " 
       ng-model="cadastroSelecionado" 
       ng-init="cadastroSelecionado=cadastros[indexDefault]" 
       id="cadastro">
        </select>
  </div>
</body>
```

---

Answer (score -1):

Obrigado pela resposta amigo.
 Porém ainda não consegui resolver.

No html:

```
<select class="form-control" name="cadastro" ng-options="cadastro.cadastroNumber for cadastro in (cadastro| orderBy:'id' | filter:{active:true}) track by simplified.id" ng-model="cadastro" ng-init="cadastro.id=cadastro[indexDefault]" id="cadastro">
```

No Angular:

```
function loadCadastro() {
    var req = gatewayClient.delivery('document').request('listActiveCadstro');
    requestMonitor.add('cmptRegisterCadastroGrid', req);
    gatewayClient.execute(req).then(function(result) {
        $rootScope.cadastro = result.data.value;
        $scope.activeSimplified = true;

         var obj = document.getElementById('myField').value;

         //Encontra o index do objeto que deve ser selecionado
           $rootScope.cadastro.map(function(value, index){
             if(cadastro.id == obj){
               alert(obj);
               $rootScope.indexDefault = index;
               return;
             }
           })

        if ($scope.simplified.length === 0) {
            messageBox.show('error', 'Erro:', 'Não existe.');
            $scope.activeSimplified = false;
        }
     })
}
```

O que posso estar fazendo de errado?

Comment: Você usou a área de respostas para adicionar esclarecimentos ou fazer uma pergunta. Em vez disso, é melhor incluir esse conteúdo na própria pergunta. Para fazer isso, basta clicar no link [edit], que fica logo abaixo da pergunta. Assim, o conteúdo fica todo reunido em um único lugar, e quem chegar aqui não precisa ficar procurando informações em várias respostas e comentários para entender o problema.